# Multiple submit button required failed

Tags: javascript, html, forms

this form multiple submit button click after required error.

```
<form>
<input type="text" required="required">
<input type="submit" name="submit1"> <<- Click input required success
<input type="submit" name="submit2"> <-- Click input required error
</form>
```

How to fix ?

Comment: Start by adding `>` to the end of the last button and then clarifying what you are trying to do and what you mean by "failed". A submit button can only submit if the `form` element is properly configured with a `method` and a `action` attribute.

Comment: update question

Comment: Your updated question still is unclear. What is your reason for having two submit buttons?

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Scot Marcus answer, the **required** attribute has no value. You could easily write your text input element as follow:

```
<input type="text" required>
```

Comment: Your "answer" isn't an answer to the question. Also, while it's true that `required` is a Boolean attribute and doesn't need a value, it is not incorrect to give it one in certain circumstances, when that is the case `required="required"` is the stated best-practice.